# Java Swing no pinta figura completa solo el borde

Tags: java, java-swing

he estado probando con java swing para practicar interfaces graficas pero el tema es que cuando dibujo un cuadrado de un determinado color solo se me pinta el borde no el relleno.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Frame extends JPanel
           implements ComponentListener{

    JLabel label;
    JFrame window;

public Frame(){

    window = new JFrame();

    window.setContentPane(this);
    window.addComponentListener(this);

    window.setSize(500, 500);
    window.setVisible(true);



    //comments

}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    int width = this.getWidth();
    int height = this.getHeight();



    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 100);

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawRect(50 + 1, 50 + 1, 100 - 1, 100 -1);
}
```

no cosigo comprender porque pasa esto de hecho he probado todo lo que he ido encontrando por internet.

Comment: Creo recordar que `drawRect` solo pinta el perimetro, para el contenido habia otro metodo.

Comment: `fillRect()`, `fillOval()`... sirven para hacer el relleno.

Answer (score 0):

El método drawRect() sólo dibuja lineas, es decir, los bordes. Si quieres tener una figura con relleno debes usar fillRect().

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
super.paint(g);
int width = this.getWidth();
int height = this.getHeight();



g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);

g.setColor(Color.red);
g.fillRect(50 + 1, 50 + 1, 100 - 1, 100 -1);
```

}

Asi quedaría el código.